# How to set the bin scripts entry point in `setup.py`?

Tags: python, setup.py

I am trying to create a package (on a Mac) which can be installed with `pip`. This package contains one main executable in the repository named `mycode.py` which I can run locally as follows:

```
python mycode.py --help
```

for example.

Given some documentation on how to create an entry point for an executable I added the following to the `setup` function in `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    name="mycode",
    author="bbp-ou-nse",
    author_email="me@email.ch",
    version="0.0.1",
    description="Some tool",
    long_description="later",
    long_description_content_type="text/x-rst",
    url="later",
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        mycode=mycode.py:main
    ''',
    install_requires=[],
    packages=find_packages(),
    python_requires=">=3.6",
)
```

and installed it with

```
pip install .
```

The installation seem to have worked, but when I now run the following command on the command line

```
mycode.py --hekp
```

I get the help of `ImageMagick`! No joke! The output starts with

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-34 Q16 x86_64 2020-10-09 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(3.1) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp xml zlib
Usage: import [options ...] [ file ]

Image Settings:
  -adjoin              join images into a single multi-image file
  -border              include window border in the output image
  -channel type        apply option to select image channels
```

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it so that I can ideally run

```
mycode --help
```

on the command line, and it executed the code `mycode.py`?

Comment: Are you using setuptools package?

Comment: `from setuptools import setup` so yes

Comment: please add ss or code inside setup.py for setup function I generally do something like this

```python
setuptools.setup(
    name="abc",
    version="alpha",
    description="DESC",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="URL",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=REQUIREMENTS
)
```

Comment: added some more code from `setup.py`

Comment: maybe because the main code is not in `bin`? Could that be the problem?

Comment: Can't attach images here so adding an answer to the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224683/discussion-between-alex-and-avisionx).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this for setup.py file

[image]

Then setup.cfg is created with following contents.

```py
[metadata]
name = mycode
version = attr: mycode.__version__
description = mycode desc
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
author = mycode

[flake8]
exclude = .git,.venv,.env,venv,env,__pycache__,docs/source/conf.py,build,dist

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    mycode=mycode.main:main
```

mycode folder will have a main.py with main function being called at entry this way!

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Do I need a `setup.py` AND a `setup.cfg`?

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Yes please create both the files

Comment: @tripleee setup.py is something op already has written added here just for reference. check comments on question

Comment: Why would you *want* to make it harder for people?

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax would look like

```py
setup(
    # ...
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['mycode=mycode.py:main']}
    # ...
)
```

Comment: But then the main code needs to define a function `main `?

Comment: Or instead of `main` put the name of an existing function which you want to execute.

Comment: .py is not needed if you want to follow this approach, just write
```python

setup(
    # ...
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['mycode=mycode.main:main']}
    # ...
)
```
mycode folder will have a main.py with main function being called at entry this way!

Better practice would be to create a setup.cfg file for config

Comment: Still does not work. the executable is not in PATH.

Comment: Where is it installed then?

Comment: I get an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Envs/mac_1.16_rcd/bin/mycode", line 5, in <module>
    from mycode.py import foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mycode'`

Comment: Then it *is* in your `PATH` but the library it wants to load is not in your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: I thought `pip install` would take care of that

Comment: It installs your library but I don't think it will check that the modules you want to `import` are actually directly possible to `import`. If you have stuff in a subdirectory, try `from subdir import mycode` and etc; but really, this is a separate question about how to properly make your code importable.

Comment: You also have to define `py_modules`. Unfortunately, this seems to be undocumented. Why is it that `setup.py` is so extremly complicated AND undocumented?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it seems to be extremely complicated and not documented!

Here is what I have inserted in the `setup` function in `setup.py`:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': ['mycode=mycode:foo']},
py_modules=['mycode'],
```

You not only have to define the entry point with `entry_points` (see [HERE](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools)), but you also have to define that `py_modules` argument (undocumented) pointing to your executable (?).

Comment: I see documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-individual-modules (though `distutils` is a weird place to document this, and will go away. There is a notice on the top of the linked page: *"This document is being retained solely until the `setuptools` documentation at https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html independently covers all of the relevant information currently included here."*).